# APE + CUE in Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, flac

I can open ape file in my Rhythmbox and it plays ok. But it doesn't fetch cue file, so I can't see songs list, only one line in the player with huge duration. What should I do to configure Rhythmbox?

Files: cd1.ape and cd1.cue

Cue text:
`... FILE "cd1.ape" WAVE  ...`

Answer (score 7):

It seems rhythmbox does not support cue lists )=
Hope it will in future.
Now you can use Clementine player for such files. It does support them!
After googling it seems only Clementine and audacious have .cue support in linux world...
But those two work for sure (checked).

Comment: Yeah, they should definitely start to support the format :) As it's the default music player on Gnome, in Fedora, and supports SoundCloud, which makes it lovable.

Answer (score 3):

I know command line music players might not be that popular, but cmus has support for cue files and many others. Is super lightweight also.

You can install it in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt install cmus
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.